# Using a sub query block in pl/sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, subquery

I have a large SQL script that is composed of sub query blocks similar to this.

```
WITH get_some_data AS (
SELECT * 
FROM table1
inner join table1.row2 r2 on table2.row2 
)
```

This block is then called in a 'main' query.

```
SELECT Row3
FROM get_some_data;
```

The thing is I want to transition this code to pl/sql so I can capture that main query but that causes the sub query to fail as it is expecting a 'SELECT INTO' instead of just a select.

I'm not missing some easy step to force a query to run without the 'INTO' clause right? 
Any way that would make it simple to transition the sub query blocks to pl/sql if not? Query runs dreadfully slow without them.

Comment: please specify your question correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am not sure what you are asking for, but if you want to convert a CTE to PLSQL, below is the example

```
BEGIN 
    FOR i IN (WITH get_some_data 
                   AS (SELECT row3 
                       FROM   table1 
                              inner join table1.row2 r2 
                                      ON table2.row2) 
              SELECT row3 
               FROM   get_some_data) LOOP 
        dbms_output.Put_line(i.row3); 
    END LOOP; 
END;
```

Comment: Yes, CTE (thanks, didn't know the 'real' term) to PLSQL was what I was looking for. I think that will help solve my issue, I'll give it a shot. Thanks a bunch!

Comment: Just finished testing, works beautifully. Thanks again!